# ARM and GCC Compiling

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, x86, arm

Hopefully this hasn't been asked and answered already, but I just had a quick question on ARM.

Specifically, if when compiling Android (which has a lot of C and C++), you use GCC to compile, doesn't that create x86 based code? How is it that an ARM processor, which uses a reduced instruction set, can interpret this code and run like it does?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no conflict to write ARM code from an x86 machine...

Comment: But it does, doesn't it? I've never known about your question, my app has a lot of C++ code and it runs perfectly on ARM, I swear.

Answer (score 3):

GCC doesn't just compile for x86.  It actually compiles to any instruction set.  If you wanted to you could create a new one just by adding a few files.

And ARM isn't a reduced instruction set.  Its a completely different instruction set.  There's some things ARM has that x86 doesn't and vice versa.

Comment: “Reduced instruction set” is a reference to [Reduced Instruction Set Computing (RISC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing), in contrast to [Complex Instruction Set Computing (CISC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing).

Comment: Ok so when compiling, it would default to x86 since most people would be using GCC to run C programs on Windows/Linux/whatever, but if you specify that you want it to run on ARM, it will make the appropriate assembly/machine code for that.

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Eh, RISC and CISC are pretty much both meaningless now.  x86 has a CISC instruction set that reduces ot a RISC set of microops.  And ARM has a ton of instructions that don't fall into a RISC model.  They're more useful as a place to discuss design philosophies than as categories nowdays.

Comment: @AnitGandhi: I have not examined how GCC is configured on different platforms, but I would expect it is generally configured to compile, by default, to the native architecture or some related subset. E.g., on Intel systems, it compiles to a common subset of the Intel architecture, on PowerPC, it compiles to PowerPC, et cetera. However, this may be configurable. Somebody installing GCC on their Intel system with the intent of working largely on ARM code could configure GCC to default to ARM.

Comment: Right @AnitGandhi.  It should just be a command line switch to tell it what output format to use.  I think the default is actually the native format, so if you ran GCC on an ARM processor running linux it would output ARM by default.

Comment: ARM stands for Advanced RISC Machines, it's at least based on a reduced instruction set.

Answer (score 3):

Building `gcc` goes through a *configuration* step, part of this is to specify a [back-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Back_end).  The *back-end* is responsible for `op-code` generation.  The typical compiler is many *phases*.  Briefly,

1. Parser - convert text to a data representation.
2. Front end  - Optimize by changing code constructs, possibly language specific.
3. Middle end - Performs *computer science* optimization that are common to any compiler.
4. Back end - Performs optimization specific to the target CPU.

See [stackoverflow compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler/info) wiki for more.

So parts *one* to *three* are common for the `x86` and the `ARM` versions of `gcc` (or any *gcc*).  The *Android compiler* is a version of `gcc` which has been configured to generate **ARM** code.  It is a different compiler than the one that normally runs on an *x86*.  You maybe running an *ARM emulator* on a PC and then believe that this code is run by the *x86*.  However, this is a [*virtual ARM machine*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/virtual-machine/info) running this code.  An `x86` processor can not run `ARM` code natively.

The *Android gcc* is an ARM configured `gcc`.  A normal *Linux distributions* `gcc` is configured for an `x86` or `x86_64`.

---

Something is missing above: *Who compiles the compiler?* In both cases, an **x86** compiler compile the new compiler. The difference is the selected *back-end*. One is **x86**, the other **ARM**. Both compilers run on an **x86**, but they generate code for different *targets*. Gcc can **only** generate code for an `ARM` **or** an `x86`; never both via any sort of command line switch.  A compiler *build* usually refers to three different CPU types.

1. **Build** - Machine where the compiler is built.  This is the compiler's compiler.
2. **Host** - the machine the compiler runs on. Not it's output, but the compiler itself.
3. **Target** - the machine the *back-end* targets.  The one code is generated for.

I think maybe people are thinking because they both run on the same *host*, they must generate code for the same *target*.  But that is not true; it is a little mind bending at first.  Depending on the setup, you may need compilers for each of these machines to make a final compiler.

The first compiler for any machine is usually a cross compiler. Except for some people who made primitive compilers long ago in assembler.

See also: [Cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Answer (score 1):

to put it simply, when you're building for ARM on your x86 computer you're using a cross-compiler - a compiler that runs on one platform but generates code for another.  This is extremely common when developing for embedded or mobile platforms.